# How to compile code into a Class with functions

Tags: python-3.x, class, pygame

I don't know how to turn this code into a class statement and then run it!

I want to have the same result as this but using class statements.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
winh = 500
winl = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((winh, winl))

width = 20

vel = 5

y = 250
x = 250

score = 0

direction = "up"

class Dot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.direction = 'right'
    def direction(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.direction = "up"
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction = "left"
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.direction = "down"
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction = "right"

p = True

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        direction = "up"
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        direction = "left"
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        direction = "down"
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        direction = "right"

    if direction == "up":
        y -= width
    if direction == "down":
        y += width
    if direction == "left":
        x -= width
    if direction == "right":
        x += width

    if y > winh - 20:
        y = 20
    if y < 20:
        y = winh - 20
    if x > winl - 20:
        x = 20
    if x < 0:
        x = winl - 20
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    dot = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, width, width))



    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

So you're class was getting there already.  A class is an *encapsulation* of data and functions that are common to that "object".  Anything for or about that object should go into this class.  But when code for keyboard handling was put into a `Dot` class, this was going in the wrong direction.  A `Dot` is a thing draw to a screen, it has a size and colour, and position.  It should not be responsible for handling user-input.  That's outside the scope of what a `Dot` is.

When updating the class, I chose to base it on the [PyGame sprite class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  This is a little bit more work at first, and it needs to be written in a particular way - have an `image`, and a `rect`, and (hopefully) an `update()` function.  But being a sprite it gets lots of functionality that's already written, including the PyGame [collision routines](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect).

Near the main loop, there's a couple of additions.  The first is creating the sprite `dotty`, and a [sprite-group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) `sprites` to hold it.  It's a bit weird to create a sprite group for a single sprite, but I assumed in the future there would be more than one.

Then in the actual loop, the code calls `sprites.update()`.  This is a handy routine that calls the `update()` function for every sprite in the group.  Then later on, there's a call to `sprites.draw( win )` which paints every sprite in the group to the screen.  This uses the sprite's `image` and the `rect` to know where, and what to paint.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
WIN_H = 500
WIN_L = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_H, WIN_L))

width = 20

vel = 5

y = 250
x = 250

score = 0

direction = "up"


class Dot( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, x,y, size=20, direction='right', colour=(0,255,0) ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.size      = size
        self.colour    = colour
        self.direction = direction
        self.image     = pygame.Surface( ( size, size ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.rect      = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x    = x
        self.rect.y    = y
        self.image.fill( colour )

    def move( self, x_dir, y_dir ):
        global WIN_H, WIN_L

        # Adjust our co-oridinates
        self.rect.x += x_dir
        self.rect.y += y_dir

        # Stay on the screen, and wrap around
        if (self.rect.left >= WIN_L ):
            self.rect.right = 0
        elif (self.rect.right <= 0 ):
            self.rect.left = WIN_L
        if (self.rect.top >= WIN_H ):
            self.rect.bottom = 0
        elif (self.rect.bottom <= 0):
            self.rect.top = WIN_H

    def update( self ):
        # TODO - handle animation, collisions, whatever
        pass


# make some sprites
dotty = Dot( x,y )
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group, for a single sprite (or more)
sprites.add( dotty )

p = True
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        direction = "up"
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        direction = "left"
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        direction = "down"
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        direction = "right"

    if direction == "up":
        dotty.move( 0, -width )
    if direction == "down":
        dotty.move( 0, width )
    if direction == "left":
        dotty.move( -width, 0 )
    if direction == "right":
        dotty.move( width, 0 )

    # update all the sprites
    sprites.update()

    # repaint the screen
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    sprites.draw( win )
    #dot = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, width, width))



    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

The movement code was moved into the `Dot` class.  This allows the `Dot` to adjust its position, but also take care of screen-wrapping issues.  If this sprite was say, some kind of projectile, maybe when it crossed the screen boundary it would call the `sprite.kill()` function to remove itself from the sprite group.  But since a `Dot` is *clearly* not a projectile, it can warp to the other side.